# python fetchall limits rows to 256

Tags: python, sqlite, pygtk

I'm using pygtk to interact with a sqlite3 database. I'm using fetchall to retrieve the data from the database and everything worked fine until I reached 256 rows. Now if I use the sqlite3 interface I can find the new records (over 256) but pygtk doesn't show them - it stops on 256th as if no more records were added.

The table schema is:

```
CREATE TABLE data_checks (
recdate date,
gto varchar(2),
payto varchar(45),
checkno varchar(10),
bank varchar(30),
iban varchar(27),
branch varchar(45),
amount float(6),
ueto date,
issuer varchar(45),
status int(1), comments text);
```

and the python code:

```
q_checks = """SELECT data_checks.rowid as rowid,recdate,gto,
    payto,checkno,bank,iban,branch,amount,dueto,issuer,aux_status.name AS Status,
    comments FROM data_checks
    JOIN aux_status ON aux_status.rowid=data_checks.status
    WHERE status !=1"""
cur.execute(q_checks)
data_checks = cur.fetchall()
```

Still `data_checks` is a list containing 256 elements and not the 266 I have in the database.

Can somebody help me?

Comment: If `data_checks` contains only 256 items, then the problem has nothing to do with pygtk, please remove the tag `pygtk`.

Comment: And what do you mean by "and not the 266 I have in the database." ?

Comment: Have you trying counting the results in sqlite shell? like `select count(*) from (SELECT data_checks.rowid as rowid,recdate,gto,
    payto,checkno,bank,iban,branch,amount,dueto,issuer,aux_status.name AS Status,
    comments FROM data_checks
    JOIN aux_status ON aux_status.rowid=data_checks.status
    WHERE status !=1)`